# global unique identifier for 2 tables in relational sql

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, database-recommendation, nosql

There are 2 sub-systems[ suppliers and retailers ] in our online market chain management system . Entry in any of those[ suppliers or retailers ] should give a globally unique ID .There would be listing and filtering of each system based on category , locations , nearest retailers .

> FYI : The query for listing retailers or suppliers is already complex which uses lots of joins and unions. So, I don't want another table for handling Unique ID .
>
> There is another option to combine retailers and suppliers entry in 1 table.
> But chances are there it may soon run out of entries if I combine retailers and suppliers entry in 1 table

Individual business entities[retailers or suppliers] have there own accounting system ,product management system , cost management system . So its a bit complex system and some of the query operations are already slow.

I have checked the possible [solutions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12715/having-a-unique-id-for-2-different-tables) but it wouldn't satisfy our needs because of performance reasons and complexity.

What should I do , should I go for NoSQL , would it solve the problem  ***or*** Is there any other solution

Comment: Explain "run out of entries".  `INT UNSIGNED` lasts for 4 billion; UUID/GUID lasts for trillions; etc.

Comment: You have relationships; so go with a RDBMS.  Don't use a NoSQL unless you want to reinvent SQL.

Comment: Beware of your `possible solutions`; it is focused on SQL Server, which is rather different (at this detail) from MySQL.

Comment: I like to prefer auto incremented primary key than using UUID/GUID since it would be faster than GUID and also client mentioned that he prefers Business id as numbers .

Comment: thanks for suggesting to stay on rdbms . Forseeing the  expansion of project from this 2 system(retailer & supplier) to adding celebrities , sport personalities,jobs... as business entities later on in our system as mentioned by client and the need for global unique numerical id, I predicted it would run out of entries if I use same table for entry of all these other subsystems(supplier,retailer,jobs,sports personalities, celebrities..).

Comment: well , I got an excellent post http://improve.dk/stop-worrying-about-exhausting-bigints/ which solved my doubt . thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to have global Unique identified for across Entities, you can go for UUID. For more details refer [here](http://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/)

Comment: A caution -- _If_ your table becomes too big to be cached, UUIDs become I/O-bound, hence slow.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of a UUID is to

- ease synchronization between two resources by eliminating the concern of collision
- to eliminate a locking contention.

If you don't need that, don't use a UUID.

> There is another option to combine retailers and suppliers entry in 1 table. But chances are there it may soon run out of entries if I combine retailers and suppliers entry in 1 table

Why would you combine the two? Combining the retailers and suppliers should be done based on the information you capture and how you query that data. Not based on ID-constraints.

UUIDs are used on big sites that view because they **NEED** them. Not because they want them. If you want to look cool without implementing infrastructure you don't understand or otherwise don't need check out [HashIDS](https://hashids.org/).